# Missing file doc comment phpcs

Tags: php

Estoy usando visual studio code para programar en PHP y de repente al crear un archivo nuevo y escribir un poco de código me aparece ese mensaje. Lo ignore pensando que NO afectaría en nada pero resulta que sí.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: si esta, solo que el mensaje lo esta tapando

Answer (score 2):

"Missing File Doc Comment".

El error lo marca la extensión phpcs, está indicando que no se encuentra el comentario del documento. Con añadir el comentario ya no avisará de su ausencia. Tiene que ser del estilo de la siguiente plantilla.

```
/**
 * PHP version 7
 *
 * @category Template_Class
 * @package  Template_Class
 * @author   Author <author@domain.com>
 * @license  https://opensource.org/licenses/MIT MIT License
 * @link     http://localhost/
 */
```

phpcs usa por defecto el standard PEAR, que tiene esta regla.

En visual studio code puedes cambiar de standard,

phpsc por defecto trae MySource, PEAR, PSR1, PSR12, PSR2, Squiz and Zend.

Yo uso PSR12, que no incluye esa norma.

Para cambiar el standard ve a

gestor de extensiones > phpcs > manage > Configure Extension Settings

En el apartado Phpcs: Standard clicka en Edit in settings.json

Añade en el json la siguiente línea con el standard que prefieras de los disponibles

```
"phpcs.standard": "PSR12"
```